# Copy stream file to printer file

Tags: ibm-midrange, ibm-ifs

I need to  use an IBM i system. The task consists in get a file stored (PCL FORMAT) into IFS and copy it (completely binary) to an output queue.

For that I follow 4 steps:

```
1) Create a FILE in QTEMP.
2) Copy IFS file to the file in QTEMP.
3) Create a Printer File linked to a Output Queue
4) Copy the QTEMP file to Printer File.
```

But in the second step the file seems to be truncated by the system.

Do anyone know how copy a stream file without being truncated?

The commands that I run  are as follows:

```
1) CRTPF QTEMP/IFSFILETP RCDLEN(8201) MBR(IFSFILETP) LVLCHK(*NO)
2) CPYFRMSTMF FROMSTMF([IFS_FILE_PATH]) TOMBR('/QSYS.LIB/QTEMP.LIB/IFSFILETP.FILE/IFSFILETP.MBR') MBROPT(*REPLACE) CVTDTA(*NONE) ENDLINFMT(*FIXED) TABEXPN(*NO)
3) CRTPRTF FILE(QTEMP/PRINTFILE) DEVTYPE(*USERASCII) OUTQ(MYLIBRARY/MYOUTPUTQUEUE)
4) CPYF FROMFILE(QTEMP/IFSFILETP) TOFILE(QTEMP/PRINTFILE)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a PCL file handy, but try something like this

```
QSH CMD('cat -c [IFS_FILE_PATH] | Rfile -wbQ -c "ovrprtf qprint outq(mylibrary/myoutputqueue) devtype(*userascii)" qprint')
```

The idea being to completely bypass copying to an intermediate QSYS.LIB file.  [Rfile](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/rzahz/rzahzrfile.htm) is unique to IBM i.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but the file in the output queue is not exactly than the original, it seems that if the register size is (for example 128 bytes), the commands completes it although is was not necessary, including 0x40 chars at the end :S